# AWS EC2上のWordpressをR53で取得したドメインで表示させられません。

Tags: nginx

[image: R53で取得したドメインで検索すると次のエラーメッセージが出ます。]

[同じエラーで悩まれた方の例を参考にしましたが、解消できないでいます。](https://teratail.com/questions/52240)

nginx configuration fileを掲載します。どこが間違っているのでしょうか？
43行目でドメイン名を指定しましたが結果に変化はありませんでした。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
コマンドの意味はまるでわかっていない初心者です。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問から読み取れないのですが、IPだとWordpressの画面が表示されるということで合ってますか？

Comment: /usr/share/nginx/html/ に WordPress をインストールしたのですか？
/usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress/ とか別の場所ではないですか？

Comment: EC2はグローバルIPアドレスをもっていますか？また、Route53でドメインを指定する場合Type: A - IPv4 addressを使うと思うので、その設定も晒してください（※個人情報はマスクしてください）

Comment: Resが大変に遅くなってしまって大変に失礼しました。

take88様。
IPアドレスからはWordpressにたどり着きます。

Taichi Yanagiya様
WordpressをどこのDirectryにインストールしたかを確認してみます。

Hiropon様
EC2はグローバルIPアドレスを持っていますので、後ほど晒します。

たぶん極めて初歩的なミスをしていると思いますが、よろしくご指導ください。汗；　　　　　　　　Ogawa